# 2 Elements fill remaining height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a div in the middle with content inside.

I wish to have the top and bottom divs fill the remaining space.

Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZmhC.png)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="top">

    </div>
    <div class="middle">
        Content
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">

    </div>
</div>
```

If possible I would like the set a min height for the top and bottom containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With flexbox you can do that

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;            /*  IE fix  */
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;              /*  IE fix  */
}
.top, .bottom {
  flex: 1;                  /*  fill remaining space  */
  background: lightblue;
}
.middle {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="top">

    </div>
    <div class="middle">
        Content
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">

    </div>
</div>
```

---

And if you need, you can also add a `min-height` to the `top`/`bottom` elements

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;            /*  IE fix  */
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;              /*  IE fix  */
}
.top, .bottom {
  flex: 1;                  /*  fill remaining space  */
  background: lightblue;
  min-height: 200px;        /*  set a min-height  */
}
.middle {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="top">

    </div>
    <div class="middle">
        Content
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great response, this appears to be exactly what I need thanks!

Comment: @WizardCoder I know you didn't say it was bad, but take a look again, IE10 support the 2012 Flexbox syntax, which in above code would be `display: -ms-flexbox;`, `-ms-flex-direction: column` and `-ms-flex: 1;`

Answer (score 0):

```css
.top{
 min-height:100px;
}
.bottom{
 min-height:100px;
}
```

or you can use different meseurment - like vh - for view height and so on
Forgot to add - it will go into your css file

Comment: But this will not fill the remaining space.

Comment: do you want to use jquery? you need to use dynamic calculation then, if yes i can show you short jquery function that can help you

Comment: Sure, If that's the easiest way. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Thanks but the other response has a pure css solution which was preferred for this post. If you still want to create a response with JQuery I won't stop you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a table solution for all you purists.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height:100%;
}
.container {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.container > div {
  display: table-row;
}
.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
}
.top, .bottom {
  background: #ADD8E6;
}
.middle {
  background: #90EE90;
  height:1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="table-cell">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="table-cell">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="table-cell">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Another great solution thanks! Is this more friendly than the flex solution?

Comment: The only reason not to use flexbox is if you wanted to support IE9. Also on large sites with complex structures flexbox can increase page load times slightly. I personally only use flexbox when there is no other way to achieve the layout I want. That all being said, in this case I can't see any problems with using flex.